# Does it matter if I use correlations or regression coefficients to suggest areas to focus on to improve overall customer satisfaction?

Tags: correlation, multiple-regression

I am working with customer satisfaction data where the dependent variable is "Overall satisfaction" and the independent variables are satisfaction with various areas such as customer support, delivery etc.

I want to suggest areas where the company should focus on in order to improve overall satisfaction.

Option 1: I could look at correlations between the 'Overall satisfaction" and the independent variables and suggest that the company focus on the top 3 positive correlations as areas for improvement.

Option 2: I can use a linear regression and suggest that the company should focus on the areas associated with the 3 highest regression coefficients.

Are the two options equivalent? If not, which one is the better approach?

Comment: This seems indirect to me. You (should) want to know what the most dissatisfied customers are dissatisfied about. That's not really a regression or correlation issue. For example, I can be very happy with quality of website, friendliness of staff, promptness of delivery but as mad as anything because the product just _doesn't work_.  Multiply me, say, because that's a widespread problem, but regressions and correlations are not optimal to find us. That's descriptive statistics and basic exploration first: these mad people, what are they mad about?

Comment: True but you also want to prioritize on areas where you think it will have the highest impact. I could be very dissatisfied in two areas but only one of which is critical to making me extremely unhappy overall. It is important then to not just look at the means but to also look at which areas drive overall satisfaction so that the company can decide where to devote limited resources if improving overall satisfaction is a goal they want to accomplish.

Comment: I don't think this management speak, which no doubt is (a) correct enough (b) what you have to work with, bears on my point at all. I said descriptive statistics: I wasn't implying that you just look at means, but at the fine structure of who is most dissatisfied. There are other pitfalls too, e.g. high correlations go with high range of responses in practice. More crucially, you are asking which is better of two methods? My reply is that neither method sounds focused on the real problems.

Comment: I understand the point you are making but let us pretend for a moment that I need to know the answer as to whether options 1 or 2 are equivalent or not for the purpose of assessing the relative contribution of the independent variables to the dependent variable. If it helps let us abstract away from the context of satisfaction and look at the issue independent of any context. I would be happy to hear about the relative pros and cons of both these options even if they are the wrong tools/approaches.

Comment: Even within your limits: Candour compels me to say that your question seems a false choice to me. If you run the regressions, the correlations are there for free; indeed you need scatter plots too. Why commit yourself in advance to a particular criterion? Your context is what defines your problem. Why throw it away?

Comment: Right. Let us stop the discussion here as it is getting far from where I want the focus to be.

Comment: Fair enough; I think you understand my point but you should see whether others can produce answers more interesting to you.

Comment: Just because one variable correlates more highly with overall satisfaction does *not* mean that changing it will have the greatest effect on overall satisfaction. I agree with @NickCox. If the problem you have stated is not your real problem, then please withdraw your post and re-post your real problem. If it *is* your real problem, listen to Nick.

Comment: @PeterFlom Why not? Doesn't a high, positive correlation mean that if one variable is high the other is also likely to be high? If the argument is that correlation is simply association and not causal then the same can be said for regression as well.

Comment: It means that there is a relationship in the data, but that doesn't mean that changing one thing will change the other. Basically, neither correlation nor regression solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, customers rate the company in various aspects of the transaction, and then, customers again give an overall score. This is the real-world structure. Making an assumption that customers are reasonably rational (i.e. consistent in their opinions), it means that somehow, they, in their minds, construct some sort of "weighted average" in order to go from the partial scores to the overall score.

Then you should use the regression approach, which reflects the above situation. Using partial correlation coefficients does not capture how one reasonably believes that the customers thought and acted when scoring the company.

This regression is in the spirit of "hedonic index regression", if we view "overall satisfaction" as the "price" of the "product" named "transacting with company", and the regressors as "features" of the product (that are provided in different levels for each customer, and hence their variability).

If the rankings are consistently coded (say, a higher number means a higher level of satisfaction for the partial scores and for the overall score), then a higher estimated regression coefficient on a partial score will indicate that this aspect of the transaction "bears more heavily" (has a higher marginal effect) on "overall satisfaction", and so indeed, focusing and improving on the areas with the higher regression coefficients, should yield larger benefits in overall satisfaction.

But also, in order to finally decide on the prioritization, one should also look how the various areas compare in average score. Say "customer support" has a higher regression coefficient than "delivery", but also, "customer support" is on average rated already very high by customers, compared to "delivery". Then the efforts to further improve "customer support" may be more costly and difficult, compared to improving "delivery". So while one unit of increase in customer support satisfaction may yield higher overall satisfaction increase compared to one unit increase in "delivery", this one unit increase may be more costly to achieve in customer satisfaction than in delivery, offsetting partially, or fully, the economic gains from the increase in "overall satisfaction".

Of course this last issue is not a statistical question, but I mentioned it so that any prioritization suggestion based on statistical analysis, at least mentions this aspect that must be taken into account for the final decisions.

Comment: I agree on the thought process part. However, why would just looking at the correlations between "Overall Satisfaction" with the components be not enough? By the way, I do not mean partial correlation but the Pearson's product-moment correlation coefficient.

Comment: Pearson's coefficient totally ignores the fact that the dependent variable "Y" varies not just because of one explanatory variable, but because of all. Then it will give you the degree of _covariance_, but not the degree of _effect_ of the explanatory variable on "Y", which is what you are after.